# Find and display continuous repeating combinations in a string

Tags: java, string, count, set

> Eg. Input : NaNaNaBCCBBNa Output : Na3 B1 C2 B2 Na1
>   Input : NaNaBCNaNaCBBNa Output : Na2 B1 C1 Na2 B2 Na1

I tried to do it this way
using Selection sort type technique

```
String input;
for (int i = 0; i < stringlength; i++) {
    for (int j = 1 ; j < stringlength; j++) {
        if (input.substring(i, i + 1).equals(input.substring(j, j + 1)) {
            count++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    userAnswer += input.substring(i, i + 1) + Integer.toString(count);
    i = i + (count-1); // to skip repeated characters
}
```

We have to count sets
Set is considered of One Capital Alphabet + consecutive next Small Alphabet (eg Na NOT CC or BB Those are just C or B, no small character with them)

Above code is rough algo (It has syntax errors)
All Suggestions welcome

Finally solved.

Comment: what does BBACBBAC return? BBAC 2 or B 2 A1 C 1 B 2 A 1 C 1?

Comment: Should ABABABAB produce AB4, ABAB2 or ABABABAB1...?  And how about AbAbCAbAbC – it it AbAb2 C1 twice or AbAbC2? And why – i.e. what is a criterion of determining the proper substring?

Comment: ABABABAB should produce A1 B1 A1 so on
@Cuero BBACBBAC should produce B2 A1 C1 B2 A1 C1

Comment: If you found your own solution, you should post it as an answer and accept it rather than posting it as an edit to the question. That way, the question & answer pair may be useful to someone down the road. Please post your own answer and revert the edit to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the method that I would use. Split the String on a regex for capital letters, then we will iterate over the items and build a mapping from element to integer. We will add or increment. After we are done we can go through and print out the items using `String.format();` for clarity.

```
UPDATED the code had not counted correctly.




   // Get User Input, replace my string with the users input below

    String[] elementArray = "NaNaNaNaBBCCDDE".split("(?=[A-Z])");

    Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

    for(String element : elementArray){

        Integer count = counts.get(element);
        if(count == null){
            counts.put(element, 1);
        } else {
            counts.replace(element, count + 1);
        }
    }

    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> mapEntry : counts.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(String.format("Element: %s%d", mapEntry.getKey(), mapEntry.getValue()));
    }




Output:

    Success time: 0.11 memory: 320512 signal:0

Element: B2
Element: Na4
Element: C2
Element: D2
Element: E1
```

Comment: @Unuderbalanced Absolute answer. I feel it will certainly work.(I havent Not tested yet, But you did :) )Thanks a LOT

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt work exactly as expected.
eg NaNaNaNaBBCCDDE output will be Na4B2C2D2E1 (Fine)

but in Scenario like this NaNaBBNaNaCCDDE output will again be same but it should be Na2 B2 Na2 C2 D2 E1

Comment: @LakhwinderSinghDhillon Oh I did not understand your intent with that. So my answer will not work.

Comment: Your answer counts every occurrence of set, whether the set is anywhere in String. We need to count consecutive set occurances. But I have certainly learned something new from you. Use of hashmaps for getting unique elements (Remove duplicates) :)

Comment: Yes it solved it. Although the answer shows just the algo not exact code. it works

Answer (score 0):

Answer is following Algorithm

```
String input;
for (int i = 0; i < stringlength; i++) {
    int count = 1; //<<<
       for (int j = /*>>>*/i + 1 /*<<<*/; j < stringlength; j++) {
        if (input.substring(i, i + 1).equals(input.substring(j, j + 1)) {
            count++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    userAnswer += input.substring(i, i + 1) + Integer.toString(count);
    i = i + (count-1); // to skip repeated characters <<<
}
```

Changes are depicted by arrows >>> <<<